# Set the headers in a Google Drive spreadsheet to move on screen as I scroll down

Tags: google-sheets

How do I set the headers in a Google Drive spreadsheet to move on screen as I scroll down the spreadsheet?

Comment: As in it’s frizzed and you want to unfreeze it?

Comment: That is a singularly unhelpful title. Can you please describe the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Typically you can set the headers to "freeze" so that the top row is always shown. This has the affect of making the headers look like they move down the screen with you.

Here's a screenshot of where you can freeze the rows in Google Docs (view > freeze rows).

[image]