# Changing the A B C ... column labels

Tags: google-sheets

[image: screen shot]

The picture above shows what I am referring to. I'm looking for a way to change these " A, B, C, ..." labels to describe better the content below each.

`A` would contain `what date`,
`B`  `what length` I run, etc.

Comment: You don't. Generally you'll put header text in row 1. You can "freeze" the row so that it is always displayed when you scroll.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/39274/29140

Answer (score 3):

In Excel these are called Headings and can be hidden or the letters changed to numbers and/or arranged right-to-left rather than the conventional left-to-right but in Google Docs is seems those options are not available. In practice there seems no way to change the Headings in Google Docs.

As suggested by @Al E. the conventional approach is to put the likes of `what date` and `what length` in Row 1. Where the spreadsheet has many rows it can be convenient to keep this Row1 visible even when scrolled down - hence `You can "freeze" the row so that it is always displayed when you scroll.` and @Jacob Jan Tuinstra's link in the comment above to [Set the headers in a Google Drive spreadsheet to move on screen as I scroll down](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39265/set-the-headers-in-a-google-drive-spreadsheet-to-move-on-screen-as-i-scroll-down/39274#39274) where how to do so is described.